# How to find the number of days with 0 qty in stock?

Tags: sql, sql-server

From the below, is there any way to calculate the number of days when the stock was out of stock. 1 in column stock shows when it was out of stock, when it changes to 0 means the stock came back in, so there is a difference of 3 days between 08/04/2022 to 11/04/2022. Not sure if this is possible.

| Itemcode | date_time | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 19/04/2022 | 0 |
| abc | 18/04/2022 | 0 |
| abc | 18/04/2022 | 1 |
| abc | 15/04/2022 | 0 |
| abc | 14/04/2022 | 0 |
| abc | 14/04/2022 | 0 |
| abc | 13/04/2022 | 0 |
| abc | 13/04/2022 | 0 |
| abc | 13/04/2022 | 0 |
| abc | 13/04/2022 | 0 |
| abc | 13/04/2022 | 0 |
| abc | 13/04/2022 | 0 |
| abc | 13/04/2022 | 0 |
| abc | 13/04/2022 | 0 |
| abc | 12/04/2022 | 1 |
| abc | 12/04/2022 | 0 |
| abc | 11/04/2022 | 0 |
| abc | 08/04/2022 | 1 |
| abc | 05/04/2022 | 0 |

Comment: Like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE Stock = 1;`?

Comment: There are many entries for the 13th, is this how the data will look?

Comment: So the column Stock is a bit which really means OutOfStock?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav this is extracted from a big query, multiple date entries are the transactions, (which is not important here). what i was trying to achieve is on 8th the stock was 0 and came back in 11th, so there was no stock for 3 days.

Comment: @SeanLange yes,

Comment: What is the result you're expecting here? How can we determine programmatically whether the 0 or 1 came first on, say, April 12th or April 18th? Does it matter if it started at 0 and increased to 1 or started at 1 and got depleted to 0? I feel like we're missing part of both the requirements and the data (or the data has been simplified so much to make it very difficult to solve the requirements as stated).

Comment: @AaronBertrand this just a part of a big query with running balance, the date shows the movement of stock where the  bit column shows when the stock was actually out of stock, scope is to find how many days we were with 0 stocks.

Comment: You didn't answer a single question I had. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand ah yes, sorry :-) This supposed to be in asc order. So the running balance starts from 05/04/22, on 8th the full stock has been sold out so the 1, again on 11th stock came back in say 0. I was hoping to find a way to calculate the number of days with 0 stock. Hope I explained well, i'm pretty new here  :-)

Comment: So using the sample data, what's your expected result? Just [Edit] the question and add the desired result in table format.

Answer (score 1):

Not fully tested, and not 100% i got the question :)  But, i'd try something with LAG or LEAD, something like this.

I hope this is a good point in the right direction for you.  Have a good eve.

```
select distinct 
t.itemcode,t.date_time,t.stock ,
datediff(d, lead(t.date_time) over (order by date_time desc),t.date_time) as DAYS_OOS
from 
tblTestabc as t
where t.stock=0
order by t.date_time desc
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use lag to get the previous date and Datediff to find the difference.
I've used group by ordercode and stock so that it will work with multiple items and show both figures. If we only want stock 0 then add `where stock = 0` and remove stock from the select and group by.

> ```
> create table stock(ordercode int,date_time date,stock int);
> insert into stock values(1,'2022-04-01',1),(1,'2022-04-04',0),(1,'2022-04-06',1),(1,'2022-04-10',0),    (1,'2022-04-15',1);
> ```

> ```
> with cte as
> (select
> *,
> datediff(d,lag(date_time)over
>   (partition by ordercode
>   order by date_time),date_time) days
>   from stock
> )
> SELECT
>   ordercode,
>   stock,
>   sum(COALESCE(days,0)) days
> from cte
> group by
>   ordercode,
>   stock
> order by
>   ordercode;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ordercode | stock | days
> --------: | ----: | ---:
>         1 |     0 |    7
>         1 |     1 |    7
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=16408b5996fe7df5ec88d7dea4329086)*